# Logstash Elasticsearch Input - runs once only?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm trying to copy a small subset of data from index A into index B.

I have a Logstash config running on an EC2 instance with the Elasticsearch input, some filters and the Elasticsearch output.

This works fine the first time I run it, but if any new data is added to Index A (that meets the input's query criteria) the Logstash config doesn't detect it and output it to Index B.

This has me thinking, does the Elasticsearch input only run once? Unlike inputs like the file or S3 input that will pick up new files added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Logstash `elasticsearch` input plugin does a single search (via scan/scroll) with an optional query and when done it quits.

You're right in that it doesn't behave the same way as the for `file` input plugin, which will simply tail one or more files and handle the new lines on the fly.

You might want to investigate the [Watcher](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/watcher/current/index.html) plugin if you need a way to be notified when a new document matches a query. Watcher could well detect the presence of a new document matching a query and then call a webhook, which could be materialized by the [`http` input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html) in your Logstash.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that Val, i'll have a look into Watcher.

Comment: Interesting finding it took me several days to get this confirmation. I needed to read from elastic, and then correlate 2 rows (with id) and then extract elapsed time between those two. For that I found a filter called elapsed, but if elastic input does a single run obviously that won't work as next time I run logstash it will forget the previous values :/

Comment: You can use the `elasticsearch` filter (instead of the input one) to make your queries + the `elapsed` one to measure the time between them.