# Logstash - elasticsearch getting only new data

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

I want to run a logstash process that grabs real-time data with certain value in the field and output it into the screen. So far i've come up with this configuration:

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost"
        user => "logstash"
        password => "logstash"
        size => 100
        query =>'{ "query" : { "bool" : { "must" : { "bool" : { "should" : [ {"match": {"field": "value2"}}, {"match": {"field": "value1"}} ] } } } } }'
    }
}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

What I've learned from running this config is that:

- Logstash output the data in batches which is determined by the size parameter.
- There's a few seconds delay between each batch
- Logstash grabbed the data from the existing data first.

My question, is there any configuration that can turn the process so that logstash will only listen for new data and output it as soon as the data come into Elastic? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: These answers might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097846/logstash-elasticsearch-input-plugin-for-streaming-data/39098551#39098551 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37163697/logstash-elasticsearch-input-runs-once-only/37163873#37163873 + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763752/how-to-generate-csv-response-in-elasticsearch/41763802#41763802

Comment: The last answer involves calling logstash on cron (e.g. every minute) and querying ES for the document indexed in the past minute.